# Find Uppercase Words with Regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a string that looks like this:

```
df = '''
ACCP ACLL ADER ADERW AEAC AEACW AHI AIRTP AKO/A AKO/B ALIT AMHCU ANDAU APOPW AUGZ AUUD AUUDW 
AVDG AVDR AYTUP BBRX BCAC BCACU BCACW BCTX BCTXW BF/A BF/B BIO/B BRK/A BRK/B BRLIU BRPAU BWL/A 
CCZ CFCV CMCTP CMPX CNNB CNTX COMSW CPTAG CPTI CRD/A CRD/B CRTDW DDI DECZ DEFN DFH DRMT DSOC EAC 
EACPW: No data found, symbol may be delisted- ECC : No data found, symbol may be delisted- ECOM :
No data found, symbol may be delisted
'''
```

And I need to extract from this string all the symbols with regex, getting something like this as result:

```
result = 'ACCP ACLL ADER ADERW AEAC AEACW AHI AIRTP AKO/A AKO/B ALIT AMHCU ANDAU APOPW AUGZ AUUD AUUDW 
AVDG AVDR AYTUP BBRX BCAC BCACU BCACW BCTX BCTXW BF/A BF/B BIO/B BRK/A BRK/B BRLIU BRPAU BWL/A 
CCZ CFCV CMCTP CMPX CNNB CNTX COMSW CPTAG CPTI CRD/A CRD/B CRTDW DDI DECZ DEFN DFH DRMT DSOC EAC 
EACPW ECC ECOM'
```

I have already tried to get all words starting with two uppercase letters with this:

```
"\b[A-Z]{2}\b"
```

And also this one:

```
"\b[A-Z]+[A-Z\/]+\b"
```

The last one works fine but only on the initial word of the string, so maybe is an issue with not taking into account the spaces between words, anyway, none worked in this case:

What would be the regex pattern needed in this case?

Comment: You haven't shown us your code. That is just as important as the regular expression. Your first example fails because it is looking for 2-character groups but your data has 4-character groups.

Comment: @BoarGules thanks for your response, I'm using regex101 by the moment, so there's no code I can show you. I have noticed that `\b` is not working in this case, it does not matches the words inside the string, only the first ans last, so that' another issue.

Comment: You could try: [`\b[A-Z]{2,}(?:\/[A-Z])?\b`](https://regex101.com/r/72Jchl/6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is a simple list comprehension.

For example:

```
df = '''
ACCP ACLL ADER ADERW AEAC AEACW AHI AIRTP AKO/A AKO/B ALIT AMHCU ANDAU APOPW AUGZ AUUD AUUDW 
AVDG AVDR AYTUP BBRX BCAC BCACU BCACW BCTX BCTXW BF/A BF/B BIO/B BRK/A BRK/B BRLIU BRPAU BWL/A 
CCZ CFCV CMCTP CMPX CNNB CNTX COMSW CPTAG CPTI CRD/A CRD/B CRTDW DDI DECZ DEFN DFH DRMT DSOC EAC 
EACPW: No data found, symbol may be delisted- ECC : No data found, symbol may be delisted- ECOM :
No data found, symbol may be delisted
'''

print([w for w in df.split() if w.isupper() and len(w) > 2])
```

Output:

```
['ACCP', 'ACLL', 'ADER', 'ADERW', 'AEAC', 'AEACW', 'AHI', 'AIRTP', 'AKO/A', 'AKO/B', 'ALIT', 'AMHCU', 'ANDAU', 'APOPW', 'AUGZ', 'AUUD', 'AUUDW', 'AVDG', 'AVDR', 'AYTUP', 'BBRX', 'BCAC', 'BCACU', 'BCACW', 'BCTX', 'BCTXW', 'BF/A', 'BF/B', 'BIO/B', 'BRK/A', 'BRK/B', 'BRLIU', 'BRPAU', 'BWL/A', 'CCZ', 'CFCV', 'CMCTP', 'CMPX', 'CNNB', 'CNTX', 'COMSW', 'CPTAG', 'CPTI', 'CRD/A', 'CRD/B', 'CRTDW', 'DDI', 'DECZ', 'DEFN', 'DFH', 'DRMT', 'DSOC', 'EAC', 'EACPW:', 'ECC', 'ECOM']
```

Comment: Definitely better than mine! Why compare single characters if you can check whole words.

Comment: I'd recommend to check for a string length too to avoid `A false positive` << emphasis on **A** =)

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly, you might want to refine this, e.g. by using a `set`, but it seemingly gets all the ticker symbols:

```py
import string 

ticker = [
    word for word in df.split() if \
    all(char in string.ascii_uppercase + '/' for char in word)
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use your second pattern `\b[A-Z]+[A-Z\/]+\b` with [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) and then join the parts together.

```
import re

df = '''
ACCP ACLL ADER ADERW AEAC AEACW AHI AIRTP AKO/A AKO/B ALIT AMHCU ANDAU APOPW AUGZ AUUD AUUDW 
AVDG AVDR AYTUP BBRX BCAC BCACU BCACW BCTX BCTXW BF/A BF/B BIO/B BRK/A BRK/B BRLIU BRPAU BWL/A 
CCZ CFCV CMCTP CMPX CNNB CNTX COMSW CPTAG CPTI CRD/A CRD/B CRTDW DDI DECZ DEFN DFH DRMT DSOC EAC 
EACPW: No data found, symbol may be delisted- ECC : No data found, symbol may be delisted- ECOM :
No data found, symbol may be delisted
'''

result = ' '.join(re.findall(r"\b[A-Z]+[A-Z\/]+\b", df))
print(result)
```

Output

```
ACCP ACLL ADER ADERW AEAC AEACW AHI AIRTP AKO/A AKO/B ALIT AMHCU ANDAU APOPW AUGZ AUUD AUUDW AVDG AVDR AYTUP BBRX BCAC BCACU BCACW BCTX BCTXW BF/A BF/B BIO/B BRK/A BRK/B BRLIU BRPAU BWL/A CCZ CFCV CMCTP CMPX CNNB CNTX COMSW CPTAG CPTI CRD/A CRD/B CRTDW DDI DECZ DEFN DFH DRMT DSOC EAC EACPW ECC ECOM
```

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/O9eAJ0)